# Ubuntu 14.04. keeps signing me out of user account

Tags: 14.04

When i log in my users account, i can stay there for exactly one minute and fifteen second and then the system keeps signing me out. Over and over again.

Comment: Is it really signing you out, or just locking the screen and requiring your password to unlock it? Have you checked the 'Brightness and Lock' settings?

Comment: Brightness and lock setting are as ususal. So everything ok there.

Answer (score 1):

Well enter into recovery mode and enter to you'r user home directory and check if you have the file called  .Xauthority.

If you have this file then check the user and group of the file if it is root then  del the file and restart your system and log in again

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem not too long ago, and as the gentleman before was saying, it is most likely due to a corrupt .Xauthority file. Terminal command is as follows:

> sudo rm /home/username/.Xauthority

Then

> sudo reboot

Let's see if that works, if not, let us know and we can go from there.

Comment: I have entered the first command, and apparently .Xauthority does not exist in my computer. I am total idiot when it comes to computers, so I beg you for further assistance.